# Changing the contrasts in regression models with R

Tags: r, statistics

I have a question about estimating a regression model in R. I have the following data (example):

```
Year   XY
2002    5  
2003    2
2004    4
2005    8
2006    3
2007    5
2008   10

the regression model I want to estimate is: 
XY = B0 + Y2005 + Y2006 + Y2007 + Y2008 + e
```

Where Y2005,Y2006,Y2007,and Y2008 are yearly indicator variables that take the value of 1 for the year 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008 and 0 otherwise.

What I need to do is to compare the value of (XY) in 2005, 2006, 2007, and 2008 to the mean value of (XY) in the period of (2002-2004).

I hope you can help me to figure out this issue and thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DF <- read.table(text = "Year   XY
                 2002    5  
                 2003    2
                 2004    4
                 2005    8
                 2006    3
                 2007    5
                 2008   10", header = TRUE)

DF$facYear <- DF$Year
DF$facYear[DF$facYear < 2005] <- "baseline"
DF$facYear <- factor(DF$facYear)

#make sure that baseline is used as intercept:
DF$facYear <- relevel(DF$facYear, "baseline")

fit <- lm(XY ~ facYear, data = DF)
summary(fit)
#Coefficients:
#            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
#(Intercept)   3.6667     0.8819   4.158   0.0533 .
#facYear2005   4.3333     1.7638   2.457   0.1333  
#facYear2006  -0.6667     1.7638  -0.378   0.7418  
#facYear2007   1.3333     1.7638   0.756   0.5286  
#facYear2008   6.3333     1.7638   3.591   0.0696 .
```

Comment: Thank you @Roland for your help